# android: onListItemClick not working

Tags: java, android

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView listview,View itemView,int position,long  id) {
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.drinks_lv);
Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this,  DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO,(int)id);
startActivity(intent);

}
```

DetailActivity.java

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_DRINKNO = "drinkNo";
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);


   int drinkNo = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNO);
   Drink drink = Drink.drinks[drinkNo];

   ImageView photo =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
   photo.setImageResource(drink.getImageResourceId());
   photo.setContentDescription(drink.getName());
   TextView name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
   name.setText(drink.getName());
   TextView description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);
   description.setText(drink.getDescription());
   }
   }
```

The first section of code is of DrinkCategoryActivity class taken from Head First Android Development-2015.It should navigate to DetailActivity class but nothing happens.The listview does not do anything on clicking the list option of drinks.It doesnot show any error but the third activity(DetailActivity does not get launched which should display image,name and description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener 
{
    final String numbers = {"1","2","3"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.riga, numbers);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adattatore, final View componente, int position, long id )
    {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), numbers[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Riga layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:textSize="36sp" />
```

Activity_main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my old app to take over what number was pressed using implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Answer (score 0):

this is how to implement click on item in listview

```
ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.drinks_lv);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this,  DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO,id);
    startActivity(intent);}
});
```

and in DetailActivity :

```
//if the type id is "int" then:
    int drinkNo = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt(EXTRA_DRINKNO);
//if it's long then use getLong
```

Comment: but i want to implement using onListItemClick method

Comment: i figured out the problem.I used setcontent view in DrinkCategory activity class and extended it to Activity class but I shd have extended ListActivity.